# how to Postgresql DB Tables recover from /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main/base/ directory?

Tags: postgresql-9.5, data-recovery

Anyone who can help us how to restore database from

```
/var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main/base/16385
```

4 directories:

```
151785
16385
16386
13687
```

I dont have any other backup of outside directory, i just have back of this directory of /base/

Comment: I just have /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main/base/ directory backup only.

Comment: Can anyone help us in this issue.